# Debugging in JavaMe (Midlet or JAD)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, emulation, midp

I can debug my application as "Emulated Java Me Midlet" or as "Emulated Java Me Jad". What is the difference between those types? Right now my app is only working in debug as emulated java me jad.

When I run it as midlet I get the following error:

> Cannot create PortForwarder with
>   necessary parameters: Failed to get
>   device id for "null"! Syntax:
>
> emulator [arguments]
>
> In order to get commands supported by
>   given device run: emulator.exe
>   -Xdevice: -Xquery

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The `"null"` device ID suggests that there probably is a configuration issue at play here. I'd suggest checking *Debug Configurations*->*Emulation* tab and checking that all's well there.

It's also possible that this you've encountered this known issue: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/eclipse_java_me_sdk_issue:

> If you have had issues with running your MIDlet in Eclipse + MTJ (Eclipse ME), then this article is relevant to you.
>
> We found out that "Run as emulated MIDlet" option is not supported by Java ME SDK 3.0.5. "Run as emulated MIDlet" means that you are executing a specific MIDlet in the jar file, where jar file contains more than one MIDlet.
>
> Please use "Run as emulated Java ME JAD" option instead...

Answer (score 1):

JAD = Java Application Descriptor. JADs are used for over-the-air (OTA) deployment. A JAD specifies one or more MIDlets to install on a device.

You've probably not configured the MIDlet deployment option correctly for the emulator. Read through the docs [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mtj.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/run.html).

Comment: The only difference between my 2 configurations is the "executable" parameter which is an absolute url when I run as Jad and a midlet class when I run as a midlet. I think eclipse can't find the emulator when I run as midlet. At the and of the error it says "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Sounds like some kind of configuration problem, then, because it's able to find the emulator for the JAD mode...